# Why is this variable is listed as unassigned local variable in C# through Mono

Tags: c#, monodevelop

I am unable to determine why the code here will not compile in MonoDevelop 2.8.2 on Win32 using Mono 2.10.6.  Monodevelop indicates that found_image_paths is an unassigned local variable?

Am I missing something here? I am new to C#

```
    string path = this.DirectoryChooser.CurrentFolder;

    Console.WriteLine ("Selected Path: " + path);

    //Iterate over all DAE files in this folder
    string[] model_paths =  Directory.GetFiles(path,"*.dae");
    HashSet<string> found_image_paths;

    foreach (string dae_path in model_paths)
    {

        XmlDocument xmlDoc= new XmlDocument(); //* create an xml document object.

        xmlDoc.Load(dae_path); //* load the XML document from the specified file.

        //* Get elements.
        XmlNodeList library_images = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("library_images");

        System.Console.WriteLine(dae_path);
        foreach (XmlNode image_node in library_images[0].ChildNodes) {
            string image_path = image_node.FirstChild.InnerText;
            found_image_paths.Add(image_path);
            Console.WriteLine(image_path);
        }



    }
    //The next line returns the error "Use of unassigned local variable 'found_image_paths'
    foreach (var item in found_image_paths) {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it is unassigned; you need to instantiate a hashset and assign it to your variable or at least assign it `null`.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct. You need to initialize it.

Comment: `HashSet<string> found_image_paths = new HashSet<string>();` appears to work.